# How to place a View in between data set of listview in android?

Tags: android

I have a listview in which i load some data from server and show in listview,I want to show a view in between data set of listview i.e. between listview. I have tried a lot but can't get success. Pls help me.

code for activity

```
            JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, m_DealListingURL, jsonObject, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                if (BuildConfig.klogInfo)
                    Log.d(TAG, "Server Response:-" + response);

                if (BuildConfig.kMonkeyInfo)
                    Log.i("Monkey", "Server Response" + response);
                Activity activity = getActivity();
                if (activity != null && isAdded()) {
                    m_LoadingProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                try {
                    int nResultCodeFromServer = Integer.parseInt(response.getString(ServerResponseStorage.s_szRESULT_CODE));
                    if (nResultCodeFromServer == ConstantInt.m_kTRANSACTION_SUCCESS) {

                        JSONArray posts = response.optJSONArray(ServerResponseStorage.s_szDEAL_ARRAY);// get Deal list in array from response
                        s_oDataset.clear();
                        for (int i = 0; i < posts.length(); i++) {// loop for counting deals from server
                            try {
                                JSONObject post = posts.getJSONObject(i);// counting deal based on index
                                item = new CDealAppDatastorage();// creating object of DealAppdata storage
                                item.setM_szHeaderText(post.getString(ServerResponseStorage.s_szDEAL_NAME));// get deal name from response
                                item.setM_szsubHeaderText(post.getString(ServerResponseStorage.s_szDEAL_CODE));// get dealcode from response
                                item.setM_szDealValue(post.getString(ServerResponseStorage.s_szDEAL_VAlUE));// get deal value from response
                                item.setViewType(0);
                                s_oDataset.add(item);// add all items in ArrayList
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                        arrayCount = posts.length();
                        // CLastCountData.getInstance().setS_szLastCount(arrayCount);
                        if (BuildConfig.klogInfo)
                            Log.d(TAG, "ArrayCount::" + arrayCount);
                        if (BuildConfig.kMonkeyInfo)
                            Log.i("Monkey", "ArrayCount::" + arrayCount);
                        /*here we are storing no. of deals coming from server*/
                        // write
                        m_oPreferenceHelper.saveIntegerValue("LastCountLength", arrayCount);


                        /*------------------------------------------------*/

                        if (!s_oDataset.isEmpty()) {// condition if data in arraylist is not empty
                            m_oAdapter = new CDealAppListingAdapter(getActivity(), s_oDataset);// create adapter object and add arraylist to adapter
                            Random rand = new Random();
                            int n = rand.nextInt(arrayCount) + 1;
                            Log.e(TAG, "Random number::" + n);
                            CDealAppDatastorage globalDealModel = new CDealAppDatastorage();
                            globalDealModel.setViewType(1);
                            s_oDataset.add(n, globalDealModel);

                            m_ListView.setAdapter(m_oAdapter);//adding adapter to listview

                            m_NoInternetWarning.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            mSwipeRefresh.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                        } else {
                            m_NoDeals.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            m_ListView.removeFooterView(mFooter);// else Load buttonvisibility set to Gone
                        }

                    }
```

code of Adapter:-

```
    public CDealAppListingAdapter(Activity m_Context, ArrayList<CDealAppDatastorage> mDataList) {
    this.m_Context = m_Context;
    s_oDataset = mDataList;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) m_Context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {// get total arraylist size
    return s_oDataset.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {// get item position in array list
    return s_oDataset.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 2;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return s_oDataset.get(position).getViewType();
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@SuppressLint({"SetTextI18n", "InflateParams"})
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        int type = getItemViewType(position);
        switch (type) {
            case 0:
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.deallisting_card_view, null);

                break;
            case 1:
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ad_view, null);
                break;

        }
        switch (type) {
            case 0:
                TextView m_Header = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.headingText);
                TextView m_DummyText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.subHeadingText);
                Button m_getBtn = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.getDealBtn);

                CDealAppDatastorage m = s_oDataset.get(position);
                m_Header.setText(m.getM_szHeaderText());
                m_DummyText.setText(m.getM_szDetails());
                m_getBtn.setText(m_Context.getResources().getString(R.string.get_text) + m.getM_szDealValue() + m_Context.getResources().getString(R.string.points_text));// set deal button text
                break;
            case 1:
                TextView t = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ads_text);

                break;
        }

    }
    return convertView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Would you like to show the layout ad_view?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ads_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Ads"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

</LinearLayout>